# Checkbox conflitando com paginação

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Estou tentando utilizar o `bootstrap-table` para criar alguns filtros em uma tabela, na primeira coluna tem um `checkbox`, que quando selecionado uma função `JQuery` copia a linha da coluna e adiciona em outra tabela, quando tira a seleção a linha da outra tabela é removida.

Até ai funciona, porem quando eu utilizo a paginação (gerada pelo `bootstrap-table`) o `checkbox` não funciona mais.

Segue o meu código:

Obs.: Tem que importar o bootstrap, bootstrap-table (http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/) e jquery

**HTML**:

```
<table id="pieces"
           data-toggle="table"
           data-page-size="2"
           data-page-list="[2,5,10,20,40,80,100]"
           data-pagination="true"
           data-id-field="id"
           data-height="460"
           data-click-to-select="true"
           data-pagination-first-text="Primieiro"
           data-pagination-pre-text="Anterior"
           data-pagination-next-text="Próximo"
           data-pagination-last-text="Último"
           data-filter-control="true">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th data-filed="select">&nbsp;</th>
                <th data-filed="id"       data-sortable="true">#</th>
                <th data-field="kind"     data-sortable="true" data-filter-control="select">Tipo</th>
                <th data-field="group"    data-sortable="true" data-filter-control="select">Grupo</th>
                <th data-field="gender"   data-sortable="true" data-filter-control="select">Gênero</th>
                <th data-field="size"     data-sortable="true" data-filter-control="select">Tamanho</th>
                <th data-field="color"    data-sortable="true" data-filter-control="select">Cor</th>
                <th data-field="used"     data-sortable="true" data-filter-control="select">Usado</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr id="1">
                <td id="select"><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox"></td>
                <td>0001</td>
                <td>Camisa</td>
                <td>Atendimento</td>
                <td>Masculino</td>
                <td>M</td>
                <td>Azul</td>
                <td> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="2">
                <td id="select"><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox"></td>
                <td>0002</td>
                <td>Calça</td>
                <td>Atendimento</td>
                <td>Masculino</td>
                <td>M</td>
                <td>Azul</td>
                <td> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="3">
                <td id="select"><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox"></td>
                <td>0003</td>
                <td>Cinto</td>
                <td>Atendimento</td>
                <td>Masculino</td>
                <td>M</td>
                <td>Azul</td>
                <td> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="4">
                <td id="select"><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox"></td>
                <td>0004</td>
                <td>Sapato</td>
                <td>Atendimento</td>
                <td>Masculino</td>
                <td>M</td>
                <td>Azul</td>
                <td> </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <hr>
    <table id="piecesToEmployer" class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>Tipo</th>
                <th>Grupo</th>
                <th>Gênero</th>
                <th>Tamanho</th>
                <th>Cor</th>
                <th>Usado</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

**JS**:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('#pieces tbody tr td input.checkbox:not(:checked)').on('change', function (e) {
        if($(this).is(':checked')){
          var row = $(this).closest('tr').clone();
          console.log(row);
          $('#piecesToEmployer tbody').append(row);
          $('#piecesToEmployer tbody #select').remove();
        } else {
          var rmRow = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
          console.log(rmRow);
          $('#piecesToEmployer #'+rmRow).remove();
        }
      });
    });
```

Segue o jsfiddle com o código: http://jsfiddle.net/zb8aomfu/

Se alguém souber qual o erro, ou como usar nativo do bootstrap-table eu agradeço muito.

Comment: Poste o trecho do código aqui também, para facilitar a análise do pessoal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é o seguinte.

Nessa linha do seu código

```
$('#pieces tbody tr td input.checkbox:not(:checked)').on('change', function (e) {....
```

Você está criando o listener do evento change dos checkboxs presentes do seu documento DOM. Porém por conta da paginação os elementos paginados não estão presentes no DOM no momento de criação do listener, por isso tirando todos os itens da página inicial da sua tabela, os demias não responderão ao evento de change.

A solução é criar o listener no **documento** e não no item, escutando a todo evento change de determinado item, porém o listener (que é a trigger do evento) está no documento e não nos elementos visíveis.

Essa é a solução:

```
  $(document).on('change', '#pieces tbody tr td input.checkbox', function (e) {
console.log('aasdasdsa');
      if($(this).is(':checked')){
      var row = $(this).closest('tr').clone();
      console.log(row);
      $('#piecesToEmployer tbody').append(row);
      $('#piecesToEmployer tbody #select').remove();
    } else {
      var rmRow = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
      console.log(rmRow);
      $('#piecesToEmployer #'+rmRow).remove();
    }
  });
```

Comment: Erick Gallani, muito boa sua resposta, ainda me ensinou alguma coisa sobre DOM. Para manter os check-boxes selecionado enquanto se usa a paginação como seria?